# Writing to a file Linux terminal

Tags: linux, sed, terminal

I am trying to delete the last line in a file. I am able to this using

```
sed '$d' 1 > 2 && cp 2 1
```

Could someone please tell me a more efficient implementation. I am able to do my task using a read,write and copy. 
Is it possible to do this using only one read and one write operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use two commands. Use `sed`'s in-place edit:

```
sed -i '$d' 1
```

Comment: Thank you KingsIndian. That was quick and very helpful